# MongoDB: find by dates nested in an object field without using $or

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My example document:

```
{
    name  : 'ABC123',
    active: false,
    meta  : {
        createdBy: 'user@gmail.com',
        created  : ISODate("2017-11-20T13:04:15.757Z"), // 13:04
        editedBy : 'user2@gmail.com',
        edited   : ISODate("2017-11-20T13:06:06.033Z"), // 13:06
        removedBy: 'user@gmail.com',
        removed  : ISODate("2017-11-20T13:09:11.033Z")  // 13:09
    }
}
```

How to query for all documents, which have either:

- `meta.created`
- `meta.updated`
- `meta.removed`

field `$gt` than date I specify (**without `$or`**)?

What I have now:

```
const d = ISODate("2017-11-20T13:00:00.033Z"); // 13:00
db
.collection('example')
.find(
    { 
        $or: ['meta.removed', 'meta.edited', 'meta.created'].map(m => { 
            return { [m]: { $gt: d } } 
        })
    } 
);
```

What I tried and didn't work:

```
const d = ISODate("2017-11-20T13:09:11.033Z"); // 13:00
db
.collection('example')
.find(
    { 
        'meta.$': { $gt: d }
    } 
);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why **without $or** ? It is quite basic logical operator. The naïve answer would be replacing it with `and-not` combinations, but I think it is not what you are asking.

Comment: Because I'm curious if it can somehow work with `$` when object field types are mixed.

Comment: I don't think `$` would work even if fields are of the same type. `$` is for arrays, and only in projection part.

Comment: Any way to query by unknown `object.key` name that you know of?

Comment: Only with aggregation